# PHP txt a line to new array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

```
PPP TXT:
123 45678 8888 
123 45678 8888
123 45678 8888

$file = file('PPP.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($file as $line) {
$words = explode(" ", $line);
print_r($words);
}
```

output array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
)
```

BUT I want output array

```
Array [0] ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
) 
Array[1] ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
) 
Array[3] ( 
    [0] => 123 
    [1] => 45678 
    [2] => 8888 
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$words[] = explode(" ", $line);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store them as a multidimensional array, push each row into an array instead of separate variables.

```
$file = file('PPP.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Instantiate the array we will store each result in
$words = [];

foreach ($file as $line) {
    // Push the result into the array
    $words[] = explode(" ", $line);
}

// Dump the array after the loop to get all of them
print_r($words);
```